# jQuery slider display multiple inputs with specific data JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to build a slider (non-range). I would like the slider to display data in 3-4 input elements (possible one select box). I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to form widgets. Using jQuery v2.1.0 and JQM v1.4.5, adding jQuery-UI is not a problem as long as it is responsive and works for mobile devices.

```
<div id="slider">
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
<input id="amount" readonly type="text">
<div class="data-display">
  <input id="result1" readonly type="text">
  <input id="result2" readonly type="text">
  <input id="result3" readonly type="text">     
  <select id="result4" readonly type="text">
</div>
```

I would like something like this fiddle I found on stack-overflow minus the calculation. No calculations are needed just data display:

http://jsfiddle.net/eqnLc9fg/1/

The data is specific/unique. The slider will display the data:

```
1st input = 149.0 F
2nd input = 100.6 C
3rd input = 57.8 psig
4th input (select) = 4.00 bar
(this would be center of the slider)

1st input = 150.0 F
2nd input = 101.1 C
3rd input = 56.8 psig
4th input (select) = 3.87 bar
```

There would be 30-50 of these sets of data in one slider. All specific, range is not possible.

Select box would also control the other inputs and slider.

Not 100% sure if slider widget is the best option for what I am trying to do. Have considered iscroll vertical or table with overflow. Slider seems like the best option to me, keeping everything in one screen. Open for suggestions as well.

I hope what I am asking is clear! ; )

___select box____       ___input box____

-----------------slider-----------------

____ input box ____      ____input box____

Thanks!

Something like this to better explain:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/VfBkk/

Comment: Although its 3 sliders (only need one) this may even be closer to what I am looking for aside from needing inputs and a select box [link]http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/VfBkk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build it something like this:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input id="result1" readonly type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <input id="result2" readonly type="text" />
  </div>
</div>

<!-- /grid-a -->
<div class="full-width-slider">
  <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" min="0" max="13" value="6" />
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input id="result3" readonly type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <select id="result4" readonly >
      <option value="0">The 1st Option</option>
      <option value="1">2Option</option>
      <option value="2">3Option</option>
      <option value="3">4Option</option>
      <option value="4">5Option</option>
      <option value="5">6Option</option>
      <option value="6">7Option</option>
      <option value="7">8Option</option>
      <option value="8">9Option</option>
      <option value="9">10Option</option>
      <option value="10">11 Option</option>
      <option value="11">12 Option</option>
      <option value="12">13 Option</option>
      <option value="13">14 Option</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS to hide the slider input and make it full width:

```
/* Hide the number input */
.full-width-slider input {
    display: none !important;
}
 .full-width-slider .ui-slider-track {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

I am using the JQM grid to lay out the controls, but you could do this other ways. Then in script catch the change event of the slider to update the inputs:

```
var menSizes = Array(14)
    menSizes[0] = [5, 6, 38];
    menSizes[1] = [5.5, 6.5, 38.5];
    menSizes[2] = [6, 7, 39];
    menSizes[3] = [6.5, 7.5, 40];
    menSizes[4] = [7, 8, 40.5];
    menSizes[5] = [8, 9, 42];
    menSizes[6] = [8.5, 9.5, 42.5];
    menSizes[7] = [9, 10, 43];
    menSizes[8] = [9.5, 10.5, 44];
    menSizes[9] = [10, 11, 44.5];
    menSizes[10] = [10.5, 11.5, 45];
    menSizes[11] = [11, 12, 46];
    menSizes[12] = [11.5, 12.5, 46.5];
    menSizes[13] = [12, 13, 47];

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
  $("#slider").on("change", function(){
    var sel = menSizes[$(this).val()];
    $("#result1").val(sel[0]);
    $("#result2").val(sel[1]);
    $("#result3").val(sel[2]);        
    $("#result4").val($(this).val()).selectmenu("refresh");
  });  
});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/phycv1cr/1/)**

Comment: Hey this is great! Thanks so much!  Quick question. Is there a way to update the 3 inputs and move slider  when the drop down is changed (selection changed). Right now slider updates select box but select box does not update other fields?

Comment: @JASONFOREST, yes, just add a change event to the select and update the slider value and trigger its change: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/phycv1cr/2/

Comment: Bang on! Perfect much appreciated.

Comment: Im sure there is a simple answer to this, can the data in the array be alphanumeric? Seems to only accept numeric data...

Comment: @JASONFOREST, works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/phycv1cr/3/  Did you put the alphnumerics in quotation marks?